# Get .val() on keydown *not* keyup

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm writing a library that amends a widget to a text area, so I need to detect when the user starts typing something:

```
this.$input.bind('keydown keyup', function() {
    if (this.$input.val() == …) { … }
}
```

The `.val()` only updates when `keyup` is triggered. That's too much of a delay. I want to know the state of the input box on `keydown`. Do you know of a library that improves `.val()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found a seemingly perfect solution](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event). Uses aforementioned HTML5 `oninput` with `onpropertychange` fallbacks for IE. Brilliant. Fantastic. Other happy words.

Answer (score 5):

too late? can't imagine a scenario where 10ms would make that much of a difference, but you could always examine the event args and get the char from there. or try [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

**edit:** there's also the [input event](http://jsfiddle.net/BhB6k/1/) that gets fired as soon as the input changes (before keyup, but after the value changes);

Comment: Since the input box's text reacts instantly to keyboard input, my widget's delayed response really sticks out.

Comment: Oh, it's a HTML5 DOM event. My work won't be *that* effortless, then.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to determine the character at `keydown`/`keypress` is by using the `event.keyCode` or `event.which` property (where `event` is an object, passed as a first argument to the event listener function).

Swap your events for the `keypress` event. This event listener is fired while the key is pressed down. `keydown` and `keyup` are only fired once. During the `keydown`/`keyup` event, multiple characters could have been added.

Answer (score 1):

For a keypress (ex. the "a" key), the `keydown` event is triggered before the "a" is appended to the text input.  You could detect the event type, and whether the `.keyCode` (or `.which`) event property was a key in the printable range, and attempt to predict what `.val()` might return after the `keyup` event, but **this is a bad idea**.

```
this.$input.bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    var val = this.$input.val();

    if (e.type == 'keydown') {
        // Here is where you would check to see if e.keyCode was a printable
        // character.  Note that key codes differ from ASCII codes. For
        // example, the "a" key will return key code 65, which is actually
        // the ASCII code for "A", so you would need to check for the presence
        // of shift keys and such.  Again, this is a bad idea :)
        val += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    }

    if (val == …) { … }
}
```

Comment: @Matthew: Because it's shoving a square peg into a round hole.  The `keydown` event, by definition, happens before anything else on a keypress.  That means that whatever controls key-to-text translation hasn't had a chance to run yet.  So it would basically be reimplementing that translation logic in a far less intuitive and comprehensive manner.  In other words, you'd be reinventing an inferior wheel.